# Swashbuckle and NGINX redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm trying to setup swashbuckle with my web API.  It's working pretty good locally with these settings :

```
app.UseSwagger(c => 
{
    c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
});
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "Swagger - API V1");
});
```

With these settings, I can successfuly access swagger via this url : http://localhost:5000/swagger

My problem is that when it is deployed on our test server, the request are redirected through Nginx this way :

- http://somepublicserver:84/myapi/swagger => http://internalserver1:5000/swagger

Unfortunately, this does not work because "http://somepublicserver:84/myapi/swagger" is always changed for "http://somepublicserver:84/swagger" when browsing which doesn't exist.

Is there any swashbuckle's settings I need to change to fix this behavior?

Comment: You mean all links on swagger ui page are pointing to the wrong location, but page itself loads correctly?

Comment: I mean it works when using the local server, but not when using the redirection.